# Can't get this AJAX request to work

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

So basically here is my script, which is in index.php  -

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "ajaxChecker.php",
            context: document.body
        }).done(function(response) { 
            if(response == true) {
                location.reload(true);  
            }
        }); 
    }, 1000 * 60);      
    </script>
```

It should each minute send request to balanceChecker.php for receiving data, and then check wether it's true reload page otherwise do nothing.

Here is ajaxChecker.php file

```
<?php

return true;

?>
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

EDITED the AJAX Part, doesn't work now also -

```
    setInterval(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "ajaxChecker.php",
            context: document.body,
            success: function(response) {
                if(response == "true") {
                    location.reload(true);  
                }
            }
        });
    }, 1000 * 10);
```

and in ajaxChecker.php file replaced return to echo and true to "true".

Comment: use `success` instead of `.done`, see my answer below...

Comment: no, sorry you don't even get the passed data in ajaxChecker.php... what about echo 1 as Random suggested?

Comment: have you tried without setInvervall? Just the ajax part itself?

Comment: ...ah, and maybe it helps if you use `$.ajax({`, have not seen `jQuery.ajax` before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You doesn't output anything by your php.

Should be:

```
<?php echo "true";?>
```

and in js:

```
if(response == "true") {
```

Also I would reccomend to not include PHP closing tag: `?>` to avoid unnecessary new lines and  to prevent sending header info:

```
<?php 
     echo "true";
```

Comment: Okay Thanks! Now i'm a little bit further, now it sends me this error - Uncaught TypeError: Object #<XMLHttpRequest> has no method 'done'

Comment: Its because jQuery ajax method you should use is `success` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Okay! Thanks gonna give it a try!

Answer (score 4):

in your php file write

```
<?php

echo true;//can also use echo 1

?>
```

Because pages can't return anything

Comment: Output `1`, because that's what `true` casts to.

Answer (score 1):

you can use "success" instead of .done:

```
var str="the data you want to send to ajaxChecker.php";

$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajaxChecker.php",
          data: str,
          success: function(msg) {
          // msg is the return you receive from ajaxChecker.php

                      if(msg==1) {location.reload();}

              }
        });
```